# Struts2 - ajax call to JSP page which calls action to render that JSP

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2

I am trying to figure out the best way to dynamically change some page html on my page using ajax and struts2. I have these tag files containing the jsp of the html that needs to be changed. I want to use these tag files for the ajax calls and not have to copy the html from them into some other source and worry about populating the data into that html, because the JSP already handles that.

So what I am doing is making a Jquery Ajax call to a jsp that simply includes the tag file I want the updated html for, and in that tag file, I am making a call to the struts2 action with the `<s:action />` tag. What I want, and what I think would be proper is if I could have that action execute, and all the struts2 jsp tags below would use the data from that action class that was executed. So for example, if I have `<s:fielderror />` tags latter on in the jsp, the field errors that were added in the action that was executed with the action tag, would be rendered in the same jsp by this fielderror tag. Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

**tag file in question:**

```
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<%-- This is the action that I want to execute and use for the rest of the jsp in this file --%>
<s:action name="ajaxRegister" namespace="/actions" />

<form id="register_form" action="register/" method="post">
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty sessionScope.username}">

        <div class="inputs">
            <h1>Create Your Password</h1>
            <label style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Create your password to finish your registration</label>
            <label for="password1">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password1" id="register_pwd_1" data-enter-click="finish_button" />
            <label for="password2">Verify Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password2" id="register_pwd_2" data-enter-click="finish_button" />
            <input name="noScript" type="hidden" value="${pageContext.request.servletPath}" data-no-script />
            <div id="register_error" class="response">
                <s:fielderror fieldName="register.error" />
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="finish_button" value="Finish" />

    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <div class="inputs">
            <h1>Not a member yet? Sign Up!</h1> 

            <input name="uuid" type="text" data-no-script />
            <div id="paste_input"></div>
            <input name="noScript" type="hidden" value="${pageContext.request.servletPath}" data-no-script />

            <div id="register_error" class="response">
                <s:fielderror fieldName="register.error" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="register_button" value="Register" />

    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</form>
```

My problem is that even though the first thing I do in this jsp is calling the action, the fielderror tags do not populate the html with the field errors that are generated in the action class. Is this possible to do? Also, I have not been able to figure out how to pass parameters as the properties to be set in the action class. The parameters that the action class needs to use are the values of that registration form that the user submits. It is that submit button that calls this jsp to render a response for them. But if I cannot get those form values to the action, then there is no point.

Also, I am not using json for this because if the register process is completed, then a totally new part of the page needs to be dynamically added, so its not just simple error messages that I am returning to the user. And I do not want to have the html in strings in the java code, or javascript, or even somewhere else, because I already have it in the JSP.

Do I have the right idea?

Comment: No. I don't really get what you're doing, it seems like there's a useless level of indirection that won't work anyway. Why can't you just call an action that renders JSP and use that HTML to fill in the div on the page the Ajax call is coming from?

Comment: I don't want to do it that way because I really don't want to have html in a java String somewhere in my code. That is really messy. However, I was initially trying to find a way to render jsp from java (and not the other way around like I am doing here), but I could not figure that out.

Comment: Why would you need to do either of those things? I'm trying to understand why your ajax call isn't to the action you actually care about.

Comment: Well I figured my problem out, but the reason I am making the ajax call to the jsp, is because the response I want is that reprocessed jsp. I am then making the call to the action from within that jsp so that the session variables and struts variable stack will be set before rendering the jsp. I also had some jstl logic in that jsp that would check if the action responded with error, and if it did, it would return the json object of that action. otherwise, it would return the reprocessed jsp. The answer to my original problem was that I had to use # to reference the variable stack